# Get Dataset from Form created by DirectCast

Tags: vb.net, dataset, directcast

I have this code that I got from somewhere that calls a form based on a certain variable:

```
Dim frm as String = "Form1"    'this may vary depending on a certain function
Dim objType As Type = Type.[GetType]("project." & frm)
Dim objForm As Form = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), Form)
```

Now on Form1 (and all the forms that can replace Form1), i have there a dataset with a name `ds`. So, when I access `ds` directly, it works.

```
Dim newds = Form1.ds
```

Now what I want is to access `ds` using `objForm`.

I have tried:

```
objForm.Controls.Find("ds")
```

But is doesn't work. I think it is because `Dataset` is part of `System.Data`

Comment: Did you add the `ds` on Form1 as real *Control* via Toolbox or just as a class variable? Additionally what do you mean with `But is doesn't work.`? What is the actual result and what the expected?

Comment: Yes it is in `Form1` and I added it via toolbox. Like I said, I can access it directly using `Form1.ds`. `But it doen's work` means `objForm.Controls.Find("ds")` returns `Nothing`. And also, when I add a breakpoint to `Watch` the contents of `objForm.Controls`, `ds` is not there. But I can see `ds` _as same level_ as `Controls` under `objForm`. It is not the same as `Textbox` because it appears _as same level_ as `Controls` and also appears under `Controls`.

Comment: It seems like datasets are not added to the form controls automatically. You could try adding it manually in the ctor of Form1: `Me.Control.Add(ds)`